# Parse json file with lots of hex characters in python

Tags: python, json, google-slides

I want to automate generation of a table of contents from a 200 slide google slide deck. Using the google slides api I got a dump  of the json representation of the deck. I plan to parse that with python and generate the table of contents.

When I try to load the json structure using json.load as shown here:

```
infile = "get_slide-1589232229433.json"
import json
d = json.load(open(infile,"r"))
```

This fails with errors on lines  where there seem to be hex characters in the middle of strings.

```
JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 259057 column 68 (char 6064484)
```

This line has the hidden hex character <0x0b> as shown below.

```
                    "content": "Flow cytometry 6 days post treatment<0x0b>Analysis of T cell subsets\n",
```

There are many strings in the document that seem "corrupted" with these hidden hex characters. I have tried manually fixing them but was wondering if there is a more elegant way of "de-hex'ing" the entire json structure. I don't know how these got introduced in the first place since the slides "look" fine on google slides.

Tried something like

```
infile = "get_slide-1589232229433.json"
outfile = open("get_slide-1589232229433_dehex.json","w")

with open(infile,"r") as _infile:
    for _line in _infile:
        outfile.write(str(_line))
```

But that file still had the same hidden <0x0b> characters.  I am half way done manually de-hexing the file..but wanted to understand how to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

`'\x0b'` is VT (Vertical Tab) character. You can simply remove them with `str.replace`:

```
import json
infile = "get_slide-1589232229433.json"
with open(infile,"r") as f:
   d = json.loads(f.read().replace('\x0b', ''))
```

Comment: Assuming OP's sample content-line is accurate, this won't actually do anything since `'<0x0b>'` != `'\x0b'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the hex character that's breaking things, it's actually the `\n` (based on your sample content anyway).

```
>>> json.loads('{"content": "Flow cytometry 6 days post treatment<0x0b>Analysis of T cell subsets\n"}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 82 (char 81)
```

vs. (note the escaped `\\n`)

```
>>> json.loads('{"content": "Flow cytometry 6 days post treatment<0x0b>Analysis of T cell subsets\\n"}')
{u'content': u'Flow cytometry 6 days post treatment<0x0b>Analysis of T cell subsets\n'}
```

Try doing a `.replace('\n', '\\n')` on your whole json string. It won't remove/fix those hex characters, but it *should* fix your decode errors.

It's important to note that if your `<0x0b>` was actually `\x0b`, *then* the hex characters would be causing issues, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: All of the lines that create the error have "<0x0b>\n" or  "<0x0b>" as part of string. There are other json strings that have "\n" which does not seem to create any issues--for eg "content": "Method\n",

Comment: There's info you're leaving out then. Using the sample line from your post, I'm able to avoid the error by escaping the newline. You could also check `infile.read()[6064484]` (the character reported in the error) to see _exactly_ what it's choking on, instead of assuming.